# Make Leaflet sidebar div active on marker click and vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, leaflet

What's the best way to change a div element to active when you click on a marker?

How to do this when you have dozens or hundreds of markers?

For example, when you click on a marker on a Leaflet map, how to make it so the sidebar element that's related to it will be active?

I can write the sudo code but I'm missing pieces.

```
markers on click
$(#sidebar div)
   make (related) li element active
```

Basically, I'm trying to mimic what a lot of map directory sites like Yelp or Foursquare do.  You click on the sidebar list item and the marker becomes active, and vice versa.  This makes it so a user and can read info about the marker while seeing where the place is.

Mapbox had a cool (now deprecated) Foursquare example. I went through the code for that but barely understood it.  That said, the example gets the point across.

[image: Foursquare Mapbox example]

When you mouseover a listitem in yelp, the marker goes black.

[image: Yelp example]

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how you have architected everything, but assuming you have the map pushpin's hold a ref to the sidebar in some way or another, just add a quick click handler. I've never done anything with leaflet before, but it looks like they support all of the events you need for the markers: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker.

So when you construct each marker, simply store off its corresponding menu item, and bind the event as show below!

```
marker.on('mouseover', function () {
    //Write code to adjust the icon
    marker.icon = someNewIcon;

    //Store a ref. to the menu item, and use that ref here to manage the view state
    currentActive.removeClass('active');
    $(this.target).addClass('active');
});
```

Hopefully this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You should try use the sidebar plugin, its very simple to use.  I've tested it with 4000 makers and it works very well.

You can find it here:
https://github.com/turbo87/leaflet-sidebar/

Comment: its not a solution . you need to provide a solution without this plugin